# Create a list and then use items as a values in the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list created in Python with a loop, and I want to assign each item of this list as a value. Sounds easy, but I need to create exactly the same number of dictionaries as I have in mu list.

```
arr_temp = []
for i in range(random.randrange(1,len(findings_list))):
    rand_item = random.choice(findings_list)
    arr_temp.append(rand_item)
# ['Lymph nodes', 'Calcifications US']
```

After doing this, I need to create 2 dictionaries with key name of "name" and value of list item, 
so in this case I would like to have something like

```
dict1 = {"name": 'Lymph nodes'}
dict2 = {"name": 'Calcifications US'}
```

Also, if you can suggest any efficient way to add an array of dictionaries to dict key, so it will look like

```
...findings: [{"name": 'Lymph nodes'}, 
              {"name": 'Calcifications US'}]
```

I will really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Would it always be two items in the list, or is a variable number of items?

Comment: It's the length of the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{'findings': [{"name":x} for x in arr_tmp]}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Spent so much time on such a simple solution.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

```
my_list = ['Lymph nodes', 'Calcifications US']
[{'name': v} for v in my_list]
[{'name': 'Lymph nodes'}, {'name': 'Calcifications US'}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Helped me to understand list comprehension combined with dicts better.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
String = ""

for i in range(1, len(arr_temp) + 1):
    String += "dict" + str(i) + " = " + {/"name/": '" + str(arr_temp[i - 1]) + "'}\n'

exec(String)
```

I **KNOW** that it's frowned upon to use `exec` or `eval`, but I'm just answering the question. If OP wants to use it, it's her choice.

Comment: Thanks, but my bad - i don't really need to rename it each time, just wanted to highlight the number of dicts created respectively.